# obtener valor de variable p y pasarla a (funcion o objeto) de esta forma p.funcion_o_objeto

Tags: javascript, poo, funciones, objeto

¿es posible crear un (objeto o funcion) que obtenga el valor de la variable de esta manera?

```
   var p="hola a todos";
   p.function_o_objeto();
```

no se como hacerlo Y tengo curiosidad si es posible. ¿si es posible de que forma se debe hacer?

Comment: cual seria el objetivo para esto? podrias explicar mejor que deseas hacer o conseguir?

Comment: me encantaria poder obtener el valor de cualquier variable con la funcion o objeto dependiendo con cual se puede hacer.

Comment: a que te refieres con obtener el valor de la variable? ya que con solo hacer referencia a `p` lo estas obteniendo o te refieres a imprimir el valor ejemplo `console.log(p)` tambien podria ser que quieres saber el tipo de variable? ejemplo `if(typeof p=== 'object' && p!== null) console.log("es un objeto!");`

Comment: pero me di cuenta que varias funciones de js obtienen el valor de la variable de esa forma ejemplo:`p.replace()` y mi pregunta es ¿puedo crear un objeto igual a esos que obtienen el valor de la variable haci?

Comment: Hola. Puedes hacerlo de varias maneras. Pero, para que entiendas los conceptos detrás de esas "funcionalidades" debes leer [Prototipos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTA**: acceder al prototype es para programadores avanzados ya que requieres un buen conocimiento del lenguaje:

si lo que deseas es agregar un nuevo metodo debes debes acceder al [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) de [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/prototype) para expandir la funcionalidad del mismo y crear uno nuevo metodo

ejemplo:

```js
// accedemos al prototype del String y le agregamos un metodo imprimirMayuscula
String.prototype.imprimirMayuscula = function(){ console.log(this.toUpperCase()) };
// creamos la variable
p="hola a todos";
// ahora string contendra el metodo imprimirMayuscula
p.imprimirMayuscula();
```

Comment: Gracias por Ayudarme. me ayudara mucho